# Pass ROWID in ListView to new Activity when clicked

Tags: sql, android-listview, onitemclick, rowid

Very new to programming here. I am working on an android application that allows the user to create and manage a database for food products that he has at home. Currently the SQL database allows you to create new database entries where each entry consists of a rowid, a product name, the amount you have of the product and finally an expiry date.

Then a ListView is populated with any existing data in the database and an OnItemClickListener for this ListView is setup to handle a click event so that if the user clicks on a row in the ListView he is send to a new edit activity. Here he can edit the name, the amount and the expiry date if needed.

Now I am trying to retrieve the data (name, amount, date) when a specific row is clicked to send it to the next activity and here's what I've got so far..

Setup a public cursor in the SQL database to get all KEYS for a specific rowid:

```
public static final String[] ALL_KEYS = new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME, KEY_AMOUNT, KEY_DATE};

public Cursor getRow(long rowId) {
    String where = KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId;
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(true,  DATABASE_TABLE, ALL_KEYS, where, null, null, null, null, null);
    if (c != null) {
        c.moveToFirst();
    }
    return c;
}
```

Then in the activity with the ListView I have the following set up to launch the new edit activity:

```
private void listViewItemClick(){
    ListView ourList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvProducts);
    ourList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Intent openProductsEdit = new Intent(Products.this,
                    ProductsEdit.class);
            startActivity(openProductsEdit);
            finish();

        }
    });
}
```

And finally I would like to set the EditTexts in my edit activity to the data passed on during the click event:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.setContentView(R.layout.products_edit);

    initiate();

    Intent getProductName = getIntent();
    String productName = getProductName.getStringExtra("productName");
    etName.setText(productName);

    Intent getProductAmount = getIntent();
    String productAmount = getProductAmount.getStringExtra("productAmount");
    etAmount.setText(productName);

    Intent getProductDate = getIntent();
    String productDate = getProductDate.getStringExtra("productDate");
    etDate.setText(productName);
```

I have been trying to retrieve the specific data for a clicked row through the cursor I have setup in the SQL database and then pass it on with openProductsEdit.putExtra in the onItemClick method, but I can't seem to successfully connect the two together.

Any suggestions on how to solve this would be greatly appreciated.

*EDIT: I solved my problem by coding my onSetItemClickListener like this*

```
private void listViewItemClick(){
    final ListView ourList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvProducts);
    ourList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Cursor cursor = (Cursor) ourList.getItemAtPosition(position);
            Intent openProductsEdit = new Intent(Products.this,
                    ProductsEdit.class);
            int rowid = cursor.getInt(0);
            String name = cursor.getString(1);
            String amount = cursor.getString(2);
            String date = cursor.getString(3);
            openProductsEdit.putExtra("rowid", rowid);
            openProductsEdit.putExtra("name", name);
            openProductsEdit.putExtra("amount", amount);
            openProductsEdit.putExtra("date", date);
            startActivity(openProductsEdit);

            finish();

        }
    });
```

Here the cursor.getString(1) sets a string to the second column of the selected row (in this case a product name). This is then passed on to an edit activity where the data is put into corresponding EditTexts.

PROBLEM SOLVED! ;)

Comment: I'm typing with thumbs here, so I can't really provide a code sample, and therefore won't submit this as an answer, but from the code you posted here, you are doing everything correctly EXCEPT for the fact that you never actually pass the data for the edit to the next activity. In your onItemClick event, where you create the Intent for launching the next activity, and before you actually start it, you should: 1. Retrieve the cursor for your row, 2. Create a new Bundle instance (new Bundle), 3. Put the data from the cursor into the bundle, 4. Set the bundle on the Intent (yourIntent.putExtras)

Comment: If that was enough to help you, I'll resubmit it as an answer so you can accept it, and then add code examples later.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I tried to add a few lines as described in the *Edit* in my post, but I am now stuck at putting the data from the cursor into the new Bundle. Any suggestions would again be of great help.

Comment: I was just about to type the same answer but it's even better that you figured it out yourself, good job! Now, Ideally, you would submit the text and code from your last edit as an answer to your own question, and then accept it, this will make your question much more helpful for any other people who might run into the same issues, as they will immediately see from the overview that the question has an accepted solution.